# How to set static IP for headless chrome

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, puppeteer, headless-browser

I have implemented headless chrome to generate PDF using pupeteer. The code is running on AWS lambda sitting on a VPC - say VPC1.

I have another service running on EC2 instance of some other VPC - say VPC2. This service constructs the page and generates URL

Headless chrome service from VPC1 makes call to EC2 instance on VPC2.

Due to security requirements, VPC1 and VPC2 has been restricted to external world. 
But I have whitelisted the security ID of VPC1 in VPC2.

Yet I am not able to generate the PDF. However, if I remove the restriction to outer world it works fine.

Is there a way to configure the static IP for headless chrome, which I can whitelist. I am not sure what IP does headless chrome use.
Or, is there any other configuration required?

Answer (score 0):

You can add static IP (AWS elastic IP) to a gateway in VPC1 as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#Add_IG_EIPs

The other way would be to use proxy server for Chrome which you would have to either manage on your own or buy from some provider.